# process.exec() in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is the code i wrote,when i execute the code,the terminal didn't output anything and the program is blocked

```
var util=require('util')
var exec=require('child_process').exec;
exec('iostat 5',function(err,stdout,stderr){
    util.puts("hello")
    util.puts(stdout)
})
```

If i change the exec command like this: it works and outputs the file list

```
var util=require('util')
var exec=require('child_process').exec;
exec('ls -al',function(err,stdout,stderr){
    util.puts("hello")
    util.puts(stdout)
})
```

is there any diffent between a block command(iostat) and nonbolck command(ls)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iostat 5` loops forever every 5 seconds and never terminates, so your exec callback will never be called. Instead you could call `iostat` from a `setInterval` call, or just remove the `5` if you only need it once.